# How can i select Interval and 1 next record in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

`SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE date>=NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY`

I need to select last day records and one more earlier. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* last day's records*/    
SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE date BETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() - 1 days) AND NOW()

UNION

/* one record from yesterday and 1000 days ago */
SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE date BETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() - 1000 days) AND (NOW() - 1 days) 
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i tried, but since i just signed up, i cant. need 15 reputation first, sry

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about *days* and not times, then this may be what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM $dbtable
WHERE date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 2 day);
```

If you use `NOW()`, you will have the time component (which does not seem desirable).

Comment: I need to select last day records and 1 more record with most recent date, but not last  day(which might be a week ago)